# export: `C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_65': not a valid identifier

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to install hadoop on my system but when I'm using the command `" bin/hadoop namenode -format"` in `cygwin` on windows the error comes:

```
" /home/EMPAdmin/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: `c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65': not a valid identifier
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set."
```

I have set environmental variable in my system and also have set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh file as: `export JAVA_HOME="c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65"`
I have tried the same file path with forward slashes too but no luck.

Please someone help me out with this issue.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you mention your Cygwin installation path?

Comment: thank you all for quick response.

My cygwin installation path is:C:\cygwin64

I have tried with: export $JAVA_HOME "c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65" but still same error.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possibilities. The first is that you *may* have something like:

```
export $JAVA_HOME
```

in your script somewhere because the *value* is being treated as the environment variable.

Putting the `$` before `JAVA_HOME` uses the current *value* as the variable name, rather than exporting the variable name, as shown in the following transcript:

```
pax> export VAR="c:\java"                 # set it correctly

pax> echo $VAR                            # check it
c:\java

pax> export VAR                           # export correctly

pax> export $VAR                          # export incorrectly
bash: export: `c:\java': not a valid identifier
```

In other words, that last line is equivalent to:

```
pax> export c:\java
```

You only use the `$` in front of variable names when you want the value, as in:

```
echo $VAR
PATH=$VAR:$PATH
```

Exporting or changing a variable should not have that at the front, instead you use the variable name:

```
export VAR
OBJ=$(echo $SRC | sed 's/cpp$/obj/')
```

That last one is special. You're *using* `SRC` so you need the `$` but you're *setting* `OBJ` so it doesn't need the `$`.

---

If you *don't* have the `$` where it shouldn't be, a second possibility is that you've got *spaces* in your `export` command where they shouldn't be, such as with:

```
export JAVA_HOME= C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65
#                ^
#                +- note this space
```

What that will do is set `JAVA_HOME` to an empty string (and try to export it) *then* attempt to export the (invalid) variable `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65`. In other words, you can do things like:

```
export xyzzy=plugh twisty=passage # set/export both xyzzy and twisty
```

I think this is actually what you're doing based on the error message and one of your comments to this answer (which includes spaces in the export command). When I enter the command with a space after the `=`, I see:

```
pax> export JAVA_HOME= c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65
bash: export: `c:Javajdk1.7.0_65': not a valid identifier
```

which is exactly what you have.

The correct way to do what you want is *without* spaces:

```
export JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65
#             \___/
#               |
#               +- no spaces on either side of the '='
```

Comment: thank you for quick response.

My cygwin installation path is:C:\cygwin64

I have tried with: export $JAVA_HOME "c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65" but still same error.

Comment: @user3876856, you misunderstood my answer. Using `$JAVA_HOME=...` is the _wrong_ thing to do. Let me try to clarify the answer with a solid example.

Comment: Thanks. now I understand your statements but it's not resolving my issue. I have tried with:export VAR="c:\java", export VAR= c:\java,export VAR=${var} etc. but none working and I'm getting the same error(not a valid identifier). if there are any specific answer plz share.

Comment: @user3876856, you need to show us that line 9 _exactly_ as it is.

Comment: # Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.  Required.
 export JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65
# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.

Comment: @user3876856, see the latest update, you comment has spaces in the export command which is a problem.